# Feedback needed on “reducing” the number of ZFC axioms by replacing the replacement schema with another.

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

First, let me make clear that, by “*"reducing" the number of axioms*”, I mean reducing the number of those axioms which do not occur from schemata. As long as we have schemata, the axioms will be infinite. The idea is simple: instead of having an axiom schema that allows us to define a set from the images of the elements, we introduce an axiom schema that allows us to define a set, from the images of subsets that are members of some partition of the original set, in such a way that these images are subsets of the new set. Then, the axiom of union becomes redundant.

In order to make the formula shorter, let us define a relation between a set and a partition of it, one that does not invoke the axiom of union. So, for any $\alpha$ and any $\beta$, $P(\beta,\alpha)$ means:

$$\forall\gamma\left(\gamma\in\alpha\rightarrow\exists\delta\left(\gamma\in\delta\wedge\delta\in\beta\right)\right)\wedge\forall\gamma\left(\gamma\in\beta\rightarrow\gamma\subseteq\alpha\wedge\gamma\neq\varnothing\wedge\forall\delta\left(\delta\in\beta\rightarrow\delta\cap\gamma=\varnothing\vee\delta=\gamma\right)\right)$$

That is, $\beta$ is a partition of $\alpha$. The existence of a partition is guaranteed from power set and specification. Furthermore, I will write the formula in a function-based form, to make it shorter and more readable. For any definable function $f$:

$$\forall\alpha\forall\beta\left[P(\beta,\alpha)\rightarrow\exists\gamma\forall\varepsilon\left(\exists\delta\left[\delta\in\beta\wedge\varepsilon=f(\delta)\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon\subseteq\gamma\right)\right]\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Then, given any set $\alpha$ and a partition $\beta$ of $\alpha$, we can define a set $\zeta$ which is the smallest one that satisfies the above:

$$\forall\varepsilon\left(\exists\delta\left[\delta\in\beta\wedge\varepsilon=f(\delta)\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon\subseteq\zeta\right)$$and$$\forall\gamma\left[\forall\varepsilon\left(\exists\delta\left[\delta\in\beta\wedge\varepsilon=f(\delta)\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon\subseteq\gamma\right)\rightarrow\zeta\subseteq\gamma\right]$$

In the case of a theory with urelements, an expression of the form $\exists\eta\left(\eta\in\varepsilon\right)$ should be added inside the $\exists\delta\left[...\right]$ part of \eqref{eq1} and the derived formulas that follow.

In order to reproduce the original schema of replacement, consider the set $\beta$ of all singleton subsets of $\alpha$. This is a partition of $\alpha$. Let $f$ be any definable function. We define $f'(\psi)=\{f(\chi)\}$ whenever $\psi=\{\chi\}$, that is, for all singleton arguments and $f'(\psi)=\varnothing$ whenever $\psi$ is not a singleton. Then, by \eqref{eq1}, there exists a set $\zeta$, such that:$$\forall\varepsilon'\left(\exists\delta'\left[\delta'\in\beta\wedge\varepsilon'=f'(\delta')\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon'\subseteq\zeta\right)$$

Since $\delta'\in\beta$, $\delta'$ is a singleton. The same goes for $\varepsilon'$, because of the definition of $f'$. Let $\delta'=\{\delta\}$ and $\varepsilon'=\{\varepsilon\}$. Then, the above becomes:

$$\forall\varepsilon\left(\exists\delta\left[\{\delta\}\in\beta\wedge\{\varepsilon\}=f'(\{\delta\})\right]\rightarrow\{\varepsilon\}\subseteq\zeta\right)$$

But $\{\delta\}\in\beta\Leftrightarrow\delta\in\alpha$ and $\{\varepsilon\}=f'(\{\delta\})\Leftrightarrow\{\varepsilon\}=\{f(\delta)\}\Leftrightarrow\varepsilon=f(\delta)$ and $\{\varepsilon\}\subseteq\zeta\Leftrightarrow\varepsilon\in\zeta$. Putting all these together, we get:

$$\forall\varepsilon\left(\exists\delta\left[\delta\in\alpha\wedge\varepsilon=f(\delta)\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon\in\zeta\right)$$

Then, if we demand that $\zeta$ is the smallest such set, we get the converse. Because, if there is an $\eta\in\zeta$ such that $\nexists\delta\left[\delta\in\alpha\wedge\delta=f(\eta)\right]$, then $\forall\varepsilon\left(\exists\delta\left[\delta\in\beta\wedge\varepsilon=f(\delta)\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon\subseteq\left(\zeta-\{\eta\}\right)\right)$ and $\zeta\nsubseteq\left(\zeta-\{\eta\}\right)$, which violates our condition. By this and by generalizations, we get the ZFC schema of replacement:

$$\forall\alpha\exists\zeta\forall\varepsilon\left(\exists\delta\left[\delta\in\alpha\wedge\varepsilon=f(\delta)\right]\leftrightarrow\varepsilon\in\zeta\right)$$

To get the ZFC axiom of union, let $e(\psi)=\chi$, whenever $\psi=\{\chi\}$, for any $\chi$ and let $e(\psi)=\varnothing$, in every other case. Let $\beta$ be again, the set of all singleton subsets of any set $\alpha$. By \eqref{eq1}, there exists a set $\zeta$, such that, for any $\varepsilon$:

$$\exists\delta'\left[\delta'\in\beta\wedge\varepsilon=e(\delta')\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon\subseteq\zeta$$

Since $\delta'\in\beta$, $\delta'$ is a singleton. Let $\delta'=\{\delta\}$. This gives: $$\exists\delta\left[\{\delta\}\in\beta\wedge\varepsilon=e(\{\delta\})\right]\rightarrow\varepsilon\subseteq\zeta$$

But $\{\delta\}\in\beta\Leftrightarrow\delta\in\alpha$ and $\varepsilon=e(\{\delta\})\Leftrightarrow\varepsilon=\delta$. Putting these in the above, we get:

$$\varepsilon\in\alpha\rightarrow\varepsilon\subseteq\zeta$$

But $\varepsilon\subseteq\zeta\Leftrightarrow\forall\eta\left(\eta\in\varepsilon\rightarrow\eta\in\zeta\right)$. So, for every $\eta$: $\varepsilon\in\alpha\rightarrow\left(\eta\in\varepsilon\rightarrow\eta\in\zeta\right)$. This is equivalent to $\eta\in\varepsilon\wedge\varepsilon\in\alpha\rightarrow\eta\in\zeta$. With existential generalization, we get:

$$\exists\varepsilon\left(\eta\in\varepsilon\wedge\varepsilon\in\alpha\right)\rightarrow\eta\in\zeta$$

Again, we can get the converse by demanding $\zeta$ to be the smallest for which the above hold. From this and by generalizations, we get the ZFC axiom of union:

$$\forall\alpha\exists\zeta\forall\eta\left[\exists\varepsilon\left(\eta\in\varepsilon\wedge\varepsilon\in\alpha\right)\leftrightarrow\eta\in\zeta\right]$$

A more restricted schema that allows only the “replacement” of singletons, will also do the job, if the reduction of the number of the (not from schemata) axioms is the only goal. But, for the system of objects I am interested in, the more general schema \eqref{eq1}, or a similar one, is needed. One of my pursuits, is to get the standard, ZFC set theory, while proceeding from a different starting point. It would help me a lot if somebody directed me towards work relevant to the above, so I wouldn't have to keep reinventing the wheel. So, the questions are:

A) Do you see any problem with the above reasoning? Feedback, please.

B) Has this or something similar been suggested before? Reference, please.

Comment: We might not have the same notion of first order theory, so I just want to point out that [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) set theory is finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: @Couchy Thanks, I have rephrased the introduction.

Comment: Since we can keep just finitely many axioms + Replacement, we can modify the instances of Replacement to include a conjunction of the finite remainder. Now all you have is one schema.